# (Neo) VIM: E523: Not allowed here

Tags: vim, neovim

I have problem (VIM: E523: Not allowed here) that reproduce randomly after I've added next keymap:

```
inoremap <silent> <C-S> <cmd> :stopinsert \| :w<CR>
```

(It is going to NORMAL mode and save file)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
inoremap <silent> <C-s> <ESC>:w<CR>
```